# how to sort my contacts from pc on google account to most frequently used. not including the default email list

Tags: contacts, gmail, google-account

How can I sort my contact list from my PC to show the most-used contacts or most-recently-used from my Google account without my Android in hand? This does not include the default 20-most-contacted email addresses that Google has.

Basically, how do I sort by most-frequently-used contacts?